# Como criar uma cópia de um elemento, através de sua propriedade

Tags: javascript, loop, condição, clone

Quero **clonar apenas as imagens cujo** o *atributo* `alt` seja "foto".

## Código

```js
var str = document.getElementById('A');

var clone = str.cloneNode(true); 
document.getElementById('B').appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<span id='A'>

<p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>

<p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/2.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>

<p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>

<p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/4.jpg" alt="poster"/></p>

<p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/5.jpg" alt="figura"/></p>

</span>

<hr>

<span id='B'> &nbsp; </span>
```

O que fiz, foi:

```
var item = document.getElementById('A').getElementsByTagName('p');

    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

    var str = item[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;

    }

if(str == "foto") {
    var clone = str.cloneNode(true); 
    document.getElementById('B').appendChild(clone);
}
```

Para isso acontecer, devo verificar se coincide com o da condição `if`. Mas não ta funcionando ainda como deveria e no console não mostra erros de sintaxe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se sabes exatamente qual é o `alt` que queres, podes usar isso num seletor CSS assim:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[alt="foto"]');
```

O código todo poderia ser assim:

```js
var fotos = document.querySelectorAll('[alt="foto"]');
var destino = document.getElementById('B');
for (var i = 0, l = fotos.length; i < l; i++) {
  var clone = fotos[i].parentElement.cloneNode(true);
  destino.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
#A {
  display: none; /* só para o exemplo */
}
```

```html
<span id='A'>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/2.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/4.jpg" alt="poster"/></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/5.jpg" alt="figura"/></p>
</span>
<hr>
<span id='B'></span>
```

Usando o teu código, corrigido, seria assim:

```js
var item = document.getElementById('A').getElementsByTagName('p');
var destino = document.getElementById('B');
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
var img = item[i].querySelector('img');
  var str = img.alt;
  if (str == "foto") {
    var clone = img.cloneNode(true);
    destino.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

```css
#A {
  display: none;
  /* só para o exemplo */
}
```

```html
<span id='A'>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/2.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="foto" /></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/4.jpg" alt="poster"/></p>
  <p><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/5.jpg" alt="figura"/></p>
</span>
<hr>
<span id='B'></span>
```

Tinhas alguns erros no teu código, nomeadamente:

- estavas a fazer `.cloneNode` da string, e não do elemento
- tinhas o `if` fora do loop `for`, e tem de estar dentro